# SQL query that conditionally places data from a column into one of 2 columns created by the query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Data is stored in a table in the following columns:

```
Date, Reference, Amount
```

The `Amount` can be a debit or credit value.

I need a query that returns the `AMOUNT` column in either a `Debit` or a `Credit` column (added by the query) as below:

```
Date          Ref          Debit      Credit
2017/04/10    ABC123      500.00
2017/04/11    XYZ321                 -500.00
```

I've tried using a `CASE` statement, but can't get the syntax right to conditionally add the `Debit` or `Credit` columns:

```
select 
    date, ref, amount, 
    case 
       when amount >= 0 
          then amount as debit 
       when amount < 0 
          then amount as credit 
    end 
from 
    dtrans
```

Comment: You need two case statements, one for each column.

Comment: can either CASE or IIF but needed for two columns

Comment: Is it possible for both Debit and Credit to be `NULL`?

Comment: How is a `0` balance recorded, i.e. is it possible for a transaction to have no value and if so, then how would that be recorded?

Answer (score 0):

IIF for 2012+ otherwise CASE

```
select date, ref, 
    IIF(amount>=0,amount,0) debit,
    IIF(amount<0,amount,0) credit
from dtrans
```

update

```
  select date, ref, 
        IIF(amount>=0,iif(amount=0,'',amount),0) debit,
        IIF(amount<0,amount,0) credit
    from dtrans
```

Comment: That works, thanks. Just a cosmetic thing: Is there a way to suppress the 0.00 (make it blank) in the Debit or Credit column when the value is in the other column?

Comment: try the updated one script but i'm going home now so you can carry on if it does not work

Comment: Perfect. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, the `IIF(amount=0,'',amount)` returns a 0.00 and not a blank. However, I found that, when used with a DataGrid, `IIF(amount>=0,amount,Null) debit` returns a blank if amount<0. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
create table #temp(Mydate date, ref varchar(10), amount int)

insert into #temp values (getdate(),'ABC123',500)

insert into #temp values (getdate()+10,'XYZ321',-500)

    select Mydate, ref, amount, 
case when amount>=0 then amount else null end as debit,
case when amount<0 then amount else null end as credit
     from #temp
```

Comment: you just translated Nick's comment to an answer :D

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select date, ref, amount, 
    case when amount>=0 then amount else null end  as Debit,
      case when amount<0 then amount else null end  as Credit 

from dtrans
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try the following...

```
SELECT date,
       ref,
       CASE
           WHEN ISNULL( debit, 0 ) > 0 THEN
               debit
           ELSE
               credit 
       END AS amount
FROM dtrans
```

The above chooses `date` and `ref` as per normal.  It then tests the `debit` field to see if it holds a `NULL` value, returning a `0` if it does or the value of `debit` if it does not.  This returned value is then compared to `0`.  Thus if the value of `debit` was not `NULL` then the `CASE` condition succeeds and the value of `debit` is chosen.  If the `CASE` condition fails then the value of `credit` is chosen.  Whichever of `debit` or `credit` is chosen, it is returned to the `SELECT` statement as the value of `amount`, meaning that our `SELECT` will always return the following fields...

```
date
ref
amount
```

If you have any questions or comments, then please feel free to post a Comment accordingly.

Comment: I have found a slight error in my code and corrected my Answer.  And it will return one column only (in addition to `date` and `ref`), namely `amount`.

Comment: fyi. following fields: Date, Reference, Amount. The Amount can be a Debit or Credit value.